# PDFParser php loading library via composer

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the library PDFparser using the composer.

I know it is installed in /home/servername/vendor/smalot/pdfparser

My php script is found in /home/servername/public_html/test.php

This is my code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',true);
    include 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
?>
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
    Warning: include(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/servername/public_html/test.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'vendor/autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/servername/public_html/test.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found in /home/servername/public_html/test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/servername/public_html/test.php on line 4
```

What am I doing wrong? This is my first time using a php library

Comment: check the folder path. vendor folder is on correct place and then check autoload.php is exist or not in vendor folder.

Comment: autoload is in /vendor/autoload.php

Comment: use `include '../vendor/autoload.php';`